# What is the best way to override/remove certain attribute in an externally hosted css (specifically Google CDN jquery-ui.css)?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-cdn

I am using Google CDN to host [one of jQuery UI theme's CSS](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css).

However there are some css properties that I would like to override.

I understand it's possible to do it with jQuery `.removeClass()` or `.css()`, but can I do it with my own css file?

For example, in the jQuery UI theme's css, there is

```
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

How would I remove the `font-size` attribute? I don't necessary want to override it. I just want to completely remove it so that the `font-size` defaults back to the `body` property of `0.75em`.

Comment: Remove: JavaScript; Override: CSS

Comment: Try `.ui-widget { font-size: inherit }`. If that's no good, this probably isn't doable.

Comment: `inherit` worked. Thanks a lot. I wish you guys posted it as an answer so I could accept.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @thirtydot stated in the comments, the `font-size` property of `.ui-widget` to `inherit`.